# Powershell Command/Script to search and delete folders and sub folders

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

good day, i was searching all over the internet for a powershell command/script that can search and delete any folder named (Games*) (game*) on remote machines 
on CMD i used to command "del /s \computername\c$\Game*" and it works perfectly with me however it delete files only, need a powershell script that can delete files and folders.

Comment: I cannot believe that you deleted *folders* using the `del` command as this deletes *files only*...

Comment: Hello and yes it's true yet i use another command to delete the folders which is 
(CMD) for /d /r . %d in (Game*) do @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d"

Comment: So I think you should add this to the question by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41115608/edit) your post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of pipeline option in powershell .Below code will do the work.

```
get-childitem -path 'FilePath' -Recurse  -Filter "Game*" | remove-item  -Force
```

Hope it HElps.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked finally -recurse with the gci was all what i needed

Answer (score 1):

```
Remove-Item \\compname1\c$\Game* -force -recurse
```

Comment: i tried this but if the folder name is Game1, Game X, it won't find it and won't delete it.

Comment: Just tested it and it works fine. try adding quotes around the path?

Comment: Thank you for your response, it works fine when the folder is created directly on "C-Drive" only however if the folder is inside "C:\users\* " "C:\whatever" it won't detect it
the CMD can search the folder/file wherever it is located it will find it and it will delete it.